# Should there be a space between [year] and BC?

Tags: punctuation, dates

This question is only about a whitespace between [year] and "BC".

Do you write

> He was born in 123BC.

or

> He was born in 123 BC.

?

Comment: I do not know of any style recommendation that tells not to use a space between the year and AD (BC, CE, BCE). Btw, why do you ask?

Comment: I ask because I currently write my bachelors thesis. I write it in English and i want it to be as good as possible. So i send it a friend who is a native speaker, she corrected the sentence where a year is and she did not leave a space there. So I wanted to know if it is a mistake of hers or of mine.

Answer (score 1):

We normally leave a space before BC, AD, BCE and CE.

Comment: And after AD as well, as AD _precedes_ the year. Also, at least according to some style guides, there should be periods.

Answer (score 0):

You ask only about the whitespace, but there are more issues with your use. There should be periods between the B and the C, for instance, at least according to some style guides. I *doubt* you will find a style guide that prescribes a period after the C but not after the B.

It depends on your style manual, but the first example I found, [National Geographic](http://stylemanual.ngs.org/home/A/AD-BC-CE-BCE) says this:

> A.D. precedes the year but follows the century.  Use only in early dates when the era might be in doubt.
>   *Pompeii was buried August 24, A.D. 79; around A.D. 79*
>   *Augustus died in A.D. 14. He died in the first century A.D.*
>
> B.C. follows the date:
>   *522 B.C.*
>   *12,000 B.C.*

**Although no explicit mention is made about a space before or after the era-indication, it is included very time.**

Also note what they mention at the bottom:

> An alternative system gaining popularity, especially in academic literature, uses C.E. (meaning the Common Era and used in place of A.D.) and B.C.E. (before the Common Era).

In the New York Times Archive, I found this [article](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/08/17/magazine/bc-ad-or-bce-ce.html) with some interesting observations. Note that in any case, a space is used between the A.D. or B.C. indication and any numbers or words next to it.

Comment: In British English most people no longer use full stops (period) with abbreviations (but I did not downvote your answer.)

Comment: Well, I did not claim you always had to use periods. I _do_ wonder about the downvoter's motivation, but I am used by now to people assuming I can read their minds. Downvoter: I actually cannot read minds, so if you want to improve the quality of the site by letting me improve my answer, you'll have to give some feedback :)